# Open multiples csv files in the folder using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The following codes below should work to load all csv files data in the datagridview by why I am getting the error of the method of operation is not implemented. Here are the codes. Do u guys have any solution

```
Imports System.IO
```

Imports System.Text
Public Class ReadBo

```
Public Shared Function ReadFile(ByVal FilePath As String) As DataTable

    Try
        Dim pathway As String() = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("File name")


        For item As Integer = 0 To pathway.Length - 1
            Dim files As New FileInfo(pathway(item))
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

            Dim Lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(files.ToString())
            Dim Fields As String()
            Fields = Lines(0).Split(New Char() {","})
            Dim Cols As Integer = Fields.GetLength(0)


            If item = 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 1 To Cols
                    dt.Columns.Add("Col" & i, GetType(String))
                Next
            End If

            For index As Integer = 0 To Lines.GetLength(0) - 1
                Fields = Lines(index).Split(New Char() {","})
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr(0) = files.Name
                For f = 1 To Cols
                    dr(f) = Fields(f - 1)
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)

            Next


        Next

        Return dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error is " + ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Function
```

End Class

```
Imports Task2.ReadBo
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        Dim initialPath As String = "C:\Users\ng.yipeng\Desktop\Task2"
        FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = initialPath
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString()

            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ReadFile(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function ReadFile(p1 As String) As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Please format your code properly and then indicate exactly where in the code the error occurs.

Comment: It appears that you have declared a method in one class, then tried to call that method in another class without specifying that it was in the first class. Instead of doing so, you then implemented it in the second class but explicitly told it to throw a `NotImplementedException` exception. It should not, then, be a surprise that it does exactly that. If your intention is to call the method in the first class then that's what you should do. Basically, you're asking us how to call a method.